# How to apply the MATCH() function only to a filtered range? Or is there another way to do that?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a filtered list of values. Let's say I have the numbers from `0` to `5`, and `2` is filtered out:

```
A (with auto-filter against "2")
0
1
3
4
5
```

Now I want to find out whether one of the values in another sheet is part of that *filtered* list. Yet, with `MATCH(2;A;0)` I still get the output `3` even though this row `3` is not in the filtered range.

The `MATCH()` function does not know the filter, that is why I get match results that are not in the filtered range.

How to apply a sort of `MATCH()` function only to a filtered range? Or is there anything else that leads to the needed output?

As it turns out from the answer, this question is almost the same for Microsoft Excel (with the very small change in newer Excel versions that you may not need the matrix trigger `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` anymore, but just `Enter`). That is why this gets an Excel tag as well.

Comment: You need to use a formula like this and it will return `#N/A` --> `=MATCH(1,IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$2),0,1))>0,IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7=Sheet2!A1,1)),0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `MS365` then you could make the above formula shorter using <kbd>LET()</kbd> and <kbd>SEQUENCE()</kbd>

[image]

---

For Older Version of Excel -->

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G5</kbd>

```
=MATCH(1,IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,
  ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$2),0,1))>0,
  IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7=Sheet1!F5,1)),0)
```

---

Or, In `MS365`

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G6</kbd>

```
=LET(α,Sheet1!A2:A7,MATCH(1,IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(α,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α))-1,0,1))>0,IF(α=F5,1)),0))
```

---

- So basically, what I am trying to achieve using the <kbd>SUBTOTAL()</kbd> function is to get the list of values which are not hidden or filtered out, in the following function the `3` denotes the <kbd>COUNTA()</kbd> while <kbd>OFFSET()</kbd> helps in creating a dynamic range. The following screenshot and the formula will give you a clear idea. Also since I am on `MS365` hence dont require to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, but older versions needs to hit.

[image]

---

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$2),0,1))
```

---

The above is same as

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(α,SEQUENCE(ROWS(α))-1,0,1))
```

---

Where `α` is the range `Sheet1!A2:A7`

---

- From the above screenshot, its seen that, the one which is filtered out i.e. `2` shows as `0`, because those which are found are the `1`s, when this part of the formula is evaluated it shows as all `FALSE` since it cant find the matching value here `2`

[image]

---

- Hence, when wrapping within <kbd>MATCH()</kbd> to get all the `TRUE` i.e. `1`s we are getting <kbd>#N/A</kbd> since it cant find it.

---

But if we try to find some other values, it will give us the required output by showing the row position. The logic applied goes same for other versions as well as for `LibreOffice` as well.

[image]

---

Now the check by the questioner for the German Libre Office (works):

- Go to `G5`.
- Paste `VERGLEICH(1;WENN(TEILERGEBNIS(3;VERSCHIEBUNG($A$2:$A$7;ZEILE($A$2:$A$7)-ZEILE($A$2);0;1))>0;WENN($A$2:$A$7=F5;1));0)`.
- Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.
- See the matrix (`{}`) function `{=VERGLEICH(1;WENN(TEILERGEBNIS(3;VERSCHIEBUNG($A$2:$A$7;ZEILE($A$2:$A$7)-ZEILE($A$2);0;1))>0;WENN($A$2:$A$7=F5;1));0)}`:

[image]

And to understand the main trick, here is how the subtotals work in the matrix:

- Mark `G7` to `G12` (or any other 5 empty cells below each other).
- Press `F2` while the 5 cells are marked.
- You will now be in the first cell of the 5 cells.
- Paste `TEILERGEBNIS(3;VERSCHIEBUNG($A$2:$A$7;ZEILE($A$2:$A$7)-ZEILE($A$2);0;1))`.
- Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.
- See the matrix of the 5 cells filled with `0` in `G9` for the `2`:

[image]

Comment: @questionto42 that sounds great, if you wish you can edit the answer and post the solution that way it would help everyone. Thanks for the great share!

Comment: Small misunderstanding in the question was that I meant column name `A` to be the name of the technical column of the spreadsheet frame. and not the column name of the table inside the spreadsheet, now in `A1`. But since that does not change anything and since any tables should have column headers, It is just as good like this.